# Custom font on simple html website will not load

Tags: html, css, django, fonts

I have been following code and examples online to try and use a custom font on my very basic html website. If it matters, I am using django.

Files of note:

aurebesh_translator.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <p>This should be in aurebesh</p>
</html>
```

main.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "aurebesh";
    src: url(aurebesh.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

p {
    font-family: aurebesh;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

These are arranged as follows:

```
| templates
| - ...
| - main.css
| - aurebesh_translator.html
| - fonts
| -- aurebesh.ttf
```

... where the aurebesh.ttf file is the associated font file for the font I want to use.

From what I can tell online, this seems to be the way it is supposed to be formatted to use my custom font. The weird thing is, if I just copy the above files to my desktop (so that only main.css, aurebesh_translator.html, and fonts/aurebesh.ttf are present) and run the aurebesh_translator.html in a browser, *it loads and uses the font successfully*! This is super weird to me, because when I include these files in the context of the rest of my website's files, it somehow stops working! I have tried opening it in chrome as well as firefox and neither work (they both just load in without my custom font).

This is the error I get from my terminal running my server when I try to access the page:

```
[01/Jun/2020 00:08:18] "GET /articles/aurebesh_translator HTTP/1.1" 200 127
Not Found: /articles/main.css
[01/Jun/2020 00:08:18] "GET /articles/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4061
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Change path to `fonts\aurebesh.ttf` in your `main.css` file

Comment: @ Ahmet Zeybek how could that be helpful? problem is main.css is not found by static tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In static folder add these files,

1. main.css
2. aurebesh.ttf
3. fonts

As you are using django, static files like css or images cannot be used directly in html. You have to load the static file in html and also change the path of the file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main.css' %}">
    <p>This should be in aurebesh</p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django when you link css/js static files use `static` tag in href attribute i.e. `href = "{% static 'path_of_file' %}"`
In this case use  `href = "{% static 'main.css' %}"`
[image: static and templates should be same directory]

Comment: Hi @Sheraram_Prajapat , thank you for your response but that does not actually fix my problem. I tried using that href pattern and also added {% load static %} to the top but nothing changed.

Comment: actually make a directory name static, near template folder and then add your css file in it. It look for static folder.

Comment: hm, even so it does not change. Won't that mean i have to adjust the main.css file as well? (I tried changing the src path and it didn't work either). Does the font/aurebesh.ttf have to go in there as well? Edit: I just tried adding that in there too and it didn't work either.

Comment: try clearing cache and cookies of your browser. sometimes it works for me. Do you still get error Not Found: /articles/main.css ?

Comment: I tried clearing it, unfortunately still doesn't work,and now, whenever I load the page, the console always says the following two lines: 

[01/Jun/2020 04:07:41] "GET /articles/aurebesh_translator HTTP/1.1" 200 138

[01/Jun/2020 04:07:41] "GET /static/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1650